# jQuery -Function not getting called correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, function

Okay this problem is pretty straight forward. I'm trying to call a this tele_in function that I have but I can't get it to run. I'm not sure what the heck I have to do. I dropped an alert in the area where I tried calling the function and it worked... What am I missing? Here is the code: The function I'm trying to call is right at the top there called "tele_in". The place I'm trying to call it has been commented out down towards the bottom. What am I doing wrong here?

```
Var SpriteVis;

jQuery(document).ready(function tele_in($) {   // function to make sprite appear.
    $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '0px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
        $("#sprite").css({
           'background-image': 'url(/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
           'height': '50px',
           'width': '90px',
           'left': '300px',
           'bottom': '80px'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sprite").css({
            'background-image': 'url(/images/test-sprite.png)',
           'height': '120px',
           'width': '96px'
            });
        }, 80);
    });
    SpriteVis = true;
});


jQuery(function ($) {
    $(window).scroll(function () {
        if (SpriteVis == true) {  //if Sprite is present on screen, run the animation sequence to make it disappear.
            $("#sprite").css({
               'background-image': 'url(/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
               'height': '50px',
               'width': '90px',
               'left': '300px',
               'bottom': '80px'
            });
            setTimeout(function () {
                $("#sprite").css({
               'background-image': 'url(/images/Teleport-Sprite.png)',
               'height': '188px',
               'width': '52px',
               'left': '330px'
                });
                $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '2000px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
                });
            }), 80;
            SpriteVis = false;
        } else {

            //I need to call the "tele_in" function here .

        }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to pull that function declaration out of the jQuery call:

```
function tele_in($) {   // function to make sprite appear.
    $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '0px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
        $("#sprite").css({
           'background-image': 'url(/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
           'height': '50px',
           'width': '90px',
           'left': '300px',
           'bottom': '80px'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
            $("#sprite").css({
            'background-image': 'url(/images/test-sprite.png)',
           'height': '120px',
           'width': '96px'
            });
        }, 80);
    });
    SpriteVis = true;
});

Query(document).ready(tele_in);
```

A function created with a function instantiation expression (as in your case) does not have its name exported to the local scope. The name is only visible from *inside* the function.

By moving that to a function declaration statement, you create a symbol in the containing scope that is visible throughout.

Note that because of the way you've defined that function, you'll have to call it like this:

```
    tele_in($);
```

or else the value of `$` in the function will be `undefined`.

Comment: Okay, I have taken the function out and declared it on it's own. I'm able to call the function when the doc is ready... but I can't call it from the other function no matter what I try. I've put in some alerts to test but the alerts only work if they are not in the tele_in function. So in other words, when I scroll, I still can't call the function. If I drop an alert into the scroll event handler, it works, but I still can't call "tele_in" in the scroll handler. Any idea why that is?

Comment: @DigitalBrent if you put the declaration of `tele_in` *inside* another function (like, a "ready" handler or something), then it will be local to that function. From what you posted it looks like they're declared in the same file as that other code from which you need to call it. Is that not really how your code looks?

Comment: I appreciate your help on this. I'm trying to understand what you're saying but I'm a little confused still. Here is a fiddle with how my code looks currently: http://jsfiddle.net/45f6pby8/

Comment: I updated the code based on your answer and moved the function out of the ready handler but now I can't call it from inside the scroll handler.

Comment: @DigitalBrent You didn't update the code properly. Look at my answer carefully and note the difference between mine and yours around the declaration of the "tele_in" function.

Comment: Okay I got it now thanks! I was not having any luck without the jQuery( in front of the tele_in function but I got rid of it and made sure my function calls all had the $ in the parameters and it worked! Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You have to declare the function outside the jquery ready handler:

```
function tele_in () {
    // ...
}

jQuery(document).ready(tele_in);
```

`$` is available in the global scope and needn't be passed as an argument to `tele_in` (unless you use multiple jquery objects, i have no experience with that scenario, not even whether it's viable).

Answer (score 0):

Since nothing is going to happen until tele_in is defined at document ready, just combine everything:

```
Var SpriteVis;

jQuery(document).ready(
  function tele_in() {   // function to make sprite appear.
    $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '0px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
      $("#sprite").css({
       'background-image': 'url(/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
       'height': '50px',
       'width': '90px',
       'left': '300px',
       'bottom': '80px'
      });
      setTimeout(function () {
        $("#sprite").css({
        'background-image': 'url(/images/test-sprite.png)',
       'height': '120px',
       'width': '96px'
        });
      }, 80);
    });
    SpriteVis = true;

    $(window).scroll(function () {
      if (SpriteVis == true) {  //if Sprite is present on screen, run the animation sequence to make it disappear.
       $("#sprite").css({
         'background-image': 'url(/images/Warp-Sprite.png)',
         'height': '50px',
         'width': '90px',
         'left': '300px',
         'bottom': '80px'
        });
        setTimeout(function () {
          $("#sprite").css({
           'background-image': 'url(/images/Teleport-Sprite.png)',
           'height': '188px',
           'width': '52px',
           'left': '330px'
            });
          $("#sprite").animate({bottom: '2000px'}, 400, 'linear', function () {
        });
      }), 80;
      SpriteVis = false;
    } else {
      tele_in();
    }
  });
});
```